# QGIS Query Filter: 0 results when too many OR operators used

Tags: sql, gis, qgis

I'm looking to filter a layer with many 1000s of rows by ID field. I have ~150 IDs that I want the filter expression to capture, but whenever I ask it to search for more than about 20 IDs I get 0 rows returned.

The first few rows of the filter expression look like this:
"id" = '3184035' 
OR "id" = '3191903' 
OR "id" = '3184108' 
OR "id" = '3185571' 
OR "id" = '3184117' 
OR "id" = '3194693' 
OR "id" = '3194710' 
...etc...

I've also tried using the IN operator and get similar results - a dozen or so lines get the result, but any more and a big fat "0".

I know i'm doing something wrong, but what!?

Comment: Please read this and refactor your question -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Please provide a complete structure SQL query.